# Wordpress: How to style my form in DIVI style

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins, divi

I created a plugin using a simple form. How to make this form look like a DIVI form?

Which classes / styles are to be applied?

My form:

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="input1">Input 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="input1" /><br>
</form>
```

Comment: What is DIVI form?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add divi's form classes directly to your . Try the page inspector (google devtools), and search for the good id or classes.